# Redirect straight to subfolder with laravel4 .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, laravel, laravel-4

In the `public` directory, I have a subfolder `/app` that contains an angularjs app. I'm trying to achieve the following situation:

- User navigates to `/, /about, /contact, etc` and sees site as handled
  by laravel.
- User navigates to `/app` (and any of it's child URLs) and is redirected to that
  subfolder (i.e. not handled by laravel's `index.php`.

How can I achieve this using the `.htaccess` file? Current file is:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

I added a redirect to the .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteRule ^((?!app/).*)$ /app/$1 [L,NC,R=301,NE]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```